# GoのリバースプロキシのResponsewriterからHTTPレスポンスのBodyを取得する方法

Tags: go

Go言語の標準ライブラリ（https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy）を用いてリバースプロキシを生成しています。下記のように実装したServeHTTP()内でHTTPレスポンスのボディを取得したいのですが、ResponseWriterからボディを取得する方法はありますか？

```
func (rp *reverseproxy) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
　　rp.ServeHTTP(w, r)
　　//ここでHTTPレスポンスのボディを表示したい
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

メモリを必要としますが、これでどうでしょうか？
(先の回答はミスがありましたので修正しました)

```
type wrapper struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    writer io.Writer
}

func (w *wrapper) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return w.writer.Write(b)
}

func (rp *ReverseProxy) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    buff := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    rp.ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP(
        &wrapper{w, io.MultiWriter(w, buff)},
        r,
    )
    // ここでbuffの内容を参照すればOK
    fmt.Print(buff.String())
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。が、コンパイルエラーとなりました。`cannot use io.MultiWriter(w, buff) (type io.Writer) as type http.ResponseWriter in argument to rp.ServeHTTP:
 io.Writer does not implement http.ResponseWriter (missing Header method)`